# Proof of this "fact" on the wikipedia for error function?

Tags: probability, integration, cumulative-distribution-functions, error-function

> Given a random variable $X ~ Norm[μ,σ]$ (a normal distribution with
> mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $σ$ and a constant $L < μ$ :
>
> $$ \begin{align} \Pr[X\leq L] &= \frac12 +
>  \frac12\operatorname{erf}\frac{L-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \\ &\approx A
>  \exp \left(-B \left(\frac{L-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) \end{align}
>  $$
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Moreover i would like to know if I can use it for the following statement :
Let $X_k$ iid $N(0,1)$ random variables for $k = 1...n$, $M_n = \underset{k=1...n}{max} X_k$

Then $Pr[M_n \leq L] \approx A^n e^{\left( -nBL^2\right)}$

Answer (score 0):

In terms of *approximation*, I do not see how this form could be obtained.

Using
$$\Phi(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
Plotting, what you could notice is that the function
$$f(x)=\frac{  e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{1-\Phi(x)}-2$$ is "close" to linearity.

Generating data for $0\leq x \leq 5$ and making the numbers rational, a quick and dirty regression gives (with $R^2=0.99999825$)
$$f(x) \sim \frac{1356 }{743}x^{1194/1069}$$ and, whatever $f(x)$ could be,
$$\Phi_{\text{app}}(x)=1-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{f(x)+2}$$

Just to give an idea
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\Phi(x)-\Phi_{\text{app}}(x)\right)^2\,dx=8.33\times 10^{-6}$$